# Is this Fastest, most Elegant and Extendable to nD implementation of AABB Intersection?

Tags: intersection, extents, computational-geometry

I recently did an **AABB** (Axes Aligned Bounding Box) Intersection implementation on 2D and 3D objects for which I came up with such a short (and very fast) solution as follows.

The demonstration below is for `2D` rectangles, nevertheless the algorithm promises extension to `3D`, and `nD` spaces as well, with no additional effort.

AABB has been a standard part of many small and huge computational geometry packages in order to speed up intersection and collision detection, for years. For me, not fan of large complicated libraries, I preferred however to do it myself with no consultation with any of them.

With the above introduction, it is quite possible that I might have missed some situations on those the following simplistic algorithm might fail.
If there was no such failure this algorithm looks like the fastest intersection test for AABB and the most easy-to-extend to nD as well as it requires only few simple numeric comparison.

**Introduction:**

An AABB is usually defined by two points as `(mins,maxs)`, e.g., in 2D `(0,0,1,1)` where `(0,0)` are the minimums for `X` and `Y` axes, and `(1,1)` are the maximums for `X` and `Y` axes respectively. Similarly for `nD` it could be as follows.

```
P = (x1,y1,z1,...,x2,y2,z2,...)
```

Let's P and Q be two AABB:

```
P(mins,maxs)                  % e.g., in 2D (0,0,1,1)
Q(mins,maxs)                  % e.g., in 2D (0.1,-1,3,2)
```

Intersection between the two P and Q happens only if:

```
P(mins) <= Q(maxs) & Q(mins) <= P(maxs)
```

So for the 2D example given above,
`P(mins) = (0,0)`  and `P(maxs) = (1,1)`
and for Q:
`Q(mins) = (0.1,-1)`  and `Q(maxs) = (3,2)`
Now if we check the conditions mentioned above:
`(0,0) <= (3,2)` i.e., `(0 <= 3)` and `(0 <= 2)` and
`(0.1,-1) <= (1,1)` i.e., `(0.1 <= 1)` and `(-1 <= 1)`, we see that all conditions satisfy which means the two AABB P and Q intersect.

Therefore the algorithm requires only few simple comparisons which can be implemented in various forms efficiently. Furthermore, the algorithm can easily be extended into nD.

**I wonder if this such simple algorithm is the fastest, the most elegant and extendable to nD for finding intersection between AABBs?**

Any comment about potential shortcoming or any discussion or share of experiences would be helpful.

[image: AABB Intersection Tests - Algorithm - (c) 2017 Developer]

[image: AABB Intersection Tests - Implementation - (c) 2017 Developer]

Comment: It seems like you are seeking a code review without providing any code.  Have you tried the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange?

Comment: @PolyGeo Here I would like only to learn your experiences and to benefit from your knowledge as this question is important in GIS community. For a case in which I have used this technique I have a post on Code Review for a complete source code at [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158956/aabb-intersections-with-space-partitions-a-sample-code-performance-and-reliabil).

Comment: @PolyGeo BTW, cannot we anymore put figures inline with the question?

Comment: Do you mean like I just moved your pictures?

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks for that. But I still only see the links in the page not figures! Strange! I checked all my other posts here at GIS as well. Why cannot I see any figures inline with the question!?

Comment: Can you see a picture (with the word `codez`) on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293172/215590).  If not, then it looks like you have something astray between you and SE sites generally, and that is something that you may need to research/ask at Meta SE.

Comment: Your title and body ask different questions, neither of which can be answered with the information provided.

Comment: @PolyGeo I checked the given link and I cannot see `codez` picture, unfortunately. I also checked my other SE sites and it has become all like this. So annoying. I will follow up a solution from Meta SE. I wonder if you and others can see the two pictures? I believe those figures are necessary to explain my question. Regardless I will edit the post to make it readable even without figures!

Comment: The two pictures seem to be visible on all my devices.

Comment: @PolyGeo I found that from today `imgur.com` and its sub-domains are all blocked in my place, very unfortunately. This might be the cause of the frustration!